# Icons for editing missing in a custom DotNetNuke Module

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am using DNN 7.00.04.

I have developed a custom module for which some icons do not show up when I log in as superuser and go into Edit mode at page level.

The following screen shot shows that only one icon displays for Exam Tracker module.
[image: Some icons do not display for custom module]

How can I ensure that the missing icons show up for the custom module?

**UPDATE:** I found that when I commented some code in code-behind of my custom module view user control, then the third icon displayed. But I don't know why the code in Page_Init event was causing the third icon (  from left) to not appear? The code for this view control is as below.

```
 Public Class viewExamTracker
    Inherits DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.PortalModuleBase   'System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        Dim x As Boolean = Me.IsEditable

        '******** CODE BELOW NEEDED TO BE COMMENTED FOR THIRD ICON to show  up******
        Dim action As DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions.ModuleAction = New DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions.ModuleAction(GetNextActionID)
        action.Title = "Add New Exam"
        action.CommandName = ""
        action.Url = EditUrl()
        action.Secure = SecurityAccessLevel.Edit
        action.Visible = True
        MyBase.Actions.Add(action)**
        'MyBase.Actions.Add(GetNextActionID, "Add New Exam", "", "", "", URL:=EditUrl(), secure:=SecurityAccessLevel.Edit, Visible:=True)
    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        'Put user code to initialize the page here

        Dim objExamTracker As New ExamTrackerController
        Dim list As ArrayList

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            list = objExamTracker.GetExamTrackerList()
            Me.grdExamTracker.DataSource = list
            Me.grdExamTracker.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: if you use a browser debug, like in firefox, is there a broken link or are the images even attempted to be requested by the browser?

Comment: That's a  good point. I will check that on my end. Thanks.

Comment: J King - After checking I found, that no images at all are being displayed for the 2 missing icons. So its definitely something else that's causing this.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few thoughts on this.  The far right icon is the "move" icon.  That is a selective display icon from DNN based on the skin layout and the other modules on the pane.  For example if you have only 1 module on the page, and you only have 1 pane in the skin it doesn't show up.  In this case, it "should" be there, so you might check your container to see if you have anything special in there that might be causing issues.

For the "edit pencil" icon, that only shows up if in your custom module you implement the IActionable interface and provide at least one action for the module.  So you will want to check that your UI class implements that interface for things to work properly.

Comment: Mitchel -Thanks for your answer. I will check my module. Do you have link for implementing IActionable interface?

Comment: Mitchel - I selected a container in module settings and also the page container in page settings, but it did not add the third icon. I added it in the pane where the top module was showing the third icon, yet it did not hlep. Is it something else?

Comment: The funny thing is if I select 'View in Layout' mode then the third icon shows for custom module. But when Page is in Edit mode, then it doesn't. So I don't think its a container issue as all other standard modules work with the default container. My module should also work, therefore.I think its something new with DNN 7 that most users/developers are not aware of.